# ASP.NET vNext - MissingMethodException: Method not found: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostic> EmitResult.get_Diagnostics()'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2015, dnvm

I upgraded this morning to VS2015 RC, and I created a new project using the ASP.NET 5 Template - Web Site. I have an error that I am not able to solve:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'System
>   .Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit.EmitResult.get_Diagnostics()'.
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.RoslynCompilationService.Compile(RelativeFileInfo
>   fileInfo, String compilationContent)

Here is the full error stack:

> MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit.EmitResult.get_Diagnostics()'.
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.RoslynCompilationService.Compile(RelativeFileInfo
>   fileInfo, String compilationContent)
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.RazorCompilationService.Compile(RelativeFileInfo
>   file)
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.CompilerCache.OnCacheMiss(RelativeFileInfo
>   file, String normalizedPath, Func`2 compile)
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.CompilerCache.GetOrAddCore(String
>   relativePath, Func`2 compile)
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.CompilerCache.GetOrAdd(String relativePath,
>   Func`2 compile)
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.VirtualPathRazorPageFactory.CreateInstance(String
>   relativePath)
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.LocatePageFromViewLocations(ActionContext
>   context, String pageName, Boolean isPartial)
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.GetRazorPageResult(ActionContext
>   context, String pageName, Boolean isPartial)
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.RazorViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext
>   context, String viewName)
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering.CompositeViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext
>   context, String viewName, Boolean partial)
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering.CompositeViewEngine.FindView(ActionContext
>   context, String viewName)
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewResult.d__20.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.FilterActionInvoker.d__44.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.FilterActionInvoker.d__43.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.FilterActionInvoker.d__42.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.FilterActionInvoker.d__37.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.FilterActionInvoker.d__32.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.d__3.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.d__2.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.Template.TemplateRoute.d__25.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.RouteCollection.d__10.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__10.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__10.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__10.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__10.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__10.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__10.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__10.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__10.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> System.Threading.Tasks.EntityFrameworkTaskExtensions.CultureAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.ErrorPageMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()

My project.json file is the same as provided in the template:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-WebApplication2-2819f43f-7688-4637-89a0-d22341b36a64",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta4",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta4"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000",
    "gen": "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration",
    "ef":  "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "postrestore": [ "npm install", "bower install" ],
    "prepare": [ "gulp copy" ]
  }
}
```

When I run a dnvm list command:

```
> dnvm list

Active Version              Runtime Architecture Location                     Alias
------ -------              ------- ------------ --------                     -----
       1.0.0-beta4          clr     x64          <mypath>\.dnx\packages
       1.0.0-beta4          clr     x86          <mypath>\.dnx\packages
       1.0.0-beta4          coreclr x64          <mypath>\.dnx\packages
       1.0.0-beta4          coreclr x86          <mypath>\.dnx\packages
       1.0.0-beta5-11596    clr     x86          <mypath>\.dnx\packages 
  *    1.0.0-beta5-11624    clr     x86          <mypath>\.dnx\packages       default
```

I tried to use as well the 1.0.0-beta5-11596 and the 1.0.0-beta4 clr but I get the same result.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Matt, I am getting the same error. From what I have heard if you try to install aspcore runtime tools from the instructions on the GitHub page along with the Visual Studio 2015, this is what is causing the error. I have tried switching to the different versions of the beta using dnvm with the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think David is right, I had the same issue and I was able to resolve it by:

- Opening the %USERPROFILE%\.dnx directory
- Deleting everything from the packages directory
- Deleting the beta5 directories from the runtimes directory
- Changing the value of the defaults.txt in the alias dir to point to one of the beta4 runtimes

Once I did that I opened the project back up, the packages restored successfully and I was able to run the application. For whatever reason the defaults.txt was  pointed at the beta5 runtime for whatever reason, assuming this was set sometime when playing around with the command line tooling.

Hope that works for you too!

Comment: Thanks David and user423293, I cleaned up and got rid of the beta5 runtime and now everything works fine!